# C++ template instantiation, what exactly does it mean?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, tmp

Now, I'm familiar with templates and I'm somewhat familiar with things like SFINAE, and I've been wondering what goes on when a template is instantiated by the compiler.

When you do things in TMP, like SFINAE, or even the simple Fibonacci sequence in TMP, it *seems* like the compiler is doing more than what I understand under *template instantiation*.  It seems the compiler is **executing** the template code.

My question is, what exactly is **template instantiation** and where is the line drawn with the compiler actually executing code?

The compiler creates a type of your template, is my understanding of template instantiation.  But in TMP it seems like it's doing a whole lot more than that, and that confuses me.

Comment: One way to better understand the way C++ templates can be used to perform calculations at runtime is to learn the basics of Prolog: template meta-programming borrows heavily from the programming style typical of Prolog.

Comment: It most assuredly does not have anything to do with PROLOG. It is a functional style more reminiscent of Haskell.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you elaborate? I've tried Prolog before and it reminds me nothing of it. I don't think Haskell is a great comparison as TMP lacks a type system.

Comment: @Pubby: It's reminiscent. Not identical or even similar. However there are many places showing where you can emulate Haskell code using TMP.

Comment: @Pubby Take a look at Prolog's [list processing](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2003k/ctl272/Bangor/clbook_22.html#1) - it is a very common pattern in Prolog to specify recursive step in a separate rule from the termination condition. Template metaprogramming uses the same pattern: there is a template that provides a step, and an explicit instantiation that provides a termination condition.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It's a common pattern in any language which is not imperative, including all of the functional ones. TMP bears a much stronger resemblance to them than the disgusting cesspit of PROLOG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to think of it as a bunch of functions, which is what it really is. Consider a class `Type`, which here represents the compiler's internal representation of a type.

```
template<typename T> class X {
    T t;
};
```

In run-time C++, you could express this as

```
Type* X(Type *t) {
    static std::unordered_map<Type*, Type*> cache;
    if (cache.find(t) != cache.end())
        return cache[t];
    Type* ret = new Type;
    ret->DataMembers.insert("t", t);
    return cache[t] = ret;
}
```

Of course, a little extra would be needed for specializations and such. Using this model, though, it's easy to two things.

A) Instantiating a template is equivalent to a function call, which happens to occur at compile-time, just like `constexpr`. Of course, a clever compiler may do something else as an optimization, but in the general case.

B) How it extends to any other functionality provided by templates.

Because instantiating a template is Turing-complete, you can't really handle it any other way. The reason it seems like the compiler is executing them is because it *is*. They are nothing more than functions in a limited EDSL with bad syntax.